# Is it possible to get a users basic profile data using facebook api with their username

Tags: facebook

My app has access to a users facebook profile url through fullcontacts api.

Can I use their username to fetch basic profile information using the facebook api without oAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can´t use the username anymore. If you try to get data of a user with the username, you will get the following error message:

> Cannot query users by their username